# How to NOT detect ending '/' with regex and sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I've been working with a regex that finds the directories from a 'ls -lF':

```
sed -n '/\/$/p'
```

Now, I want this to work with NOT directories (i.e. files, but not symlinks). How should I do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Do you mean `sed -n '/[^\/]$/p'`?

Comment: Almost! Thanks. I'd like to exclude also symlinks, which include '->' in the command. I tried to add to your regex that exception, but I had no success.

Comment: If you don't want to detect something using `sed`, then don't run `sed`, so simple.

Comment: Then, how can I get the strings from 'ls' not using sed? I can't find any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -lF | sed -n '/\/$/!p'
# --------------------^------
```

As in many places in Unix, ! negates a test. Or maybe you're familiar with `-v` negation in the `grep` family of tools.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

[Don't try to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use the appropriate predicates with the `find` command, or look at the primaries available with the `test` command.

```
find . ! -type d
```

or

```
for f in *; do
    if ! [ -d "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Using `find` is indeed much better than parsing ls. If needed to find only direct children use `-maxdepth 1`. Also it seems he wants only regular files (not symlinks, and supposedly not fifos or device files..). So my suggestion is: `find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f`